# does microtask queue instructions have higher priority than root-level instructions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, event-loop

```js
const anotherAsync = async () => {
  console.log('Another async called');
  for (let i=0; i<=100000; i++) {

  }
  console.log('Another async finished');
};

const func = async () => {
  console.log('async func called');
  anotherAsync();
  console.log('async func finished');
};

const run = async () => {
  console.log('calling async func');
  await func();
  console.log('done');
};

run();
```

The result:

```
calling async func
async func called
Another async called
Another async finished
async func finished
done
```

Here, as you can see I am awaiting only on `func` function. `anotherAsync` is not awaited. So, logically I would assume `async func finished` and `done` to be printed before `Another async called` as `anotherAsync()` should be in microtask queue untill the callstack is not yet empty. But here it does not seem to be the case.
Will appreciate if someone can help me understand why `Another async function` is printed before `async func finished`

My assumption is that, `anotherFunc` is part of `func` which is why `await` on `func` does trigger an implicit await on `anotherFunc` or prioritizes the execution of those instructions for that function

Comment: What is a "root-level instruction"?

Comment: Function calls are not placed in the microtask queue, they're synchronous and follow run-to-completion semantics as usual. Putting `async` on a function declaration does not make its code run in the background, with lesser priority, or anything. The microtask queue contains `then` callbacks and `await` resumptions: the only thing in your code that could be deferred by the microtask queue is that the statement `console.log('done')`, since it comes after an `await`.

Comment: "*why "Another async function" is printed before "async func finished"?*" - because your `anotherAsync` does not use `await` anywhere, or do asynchronous things (like timeouts or network requests) and log after they're completed. If it did, you'd get the results you are expecting. A loop with many iterations is not asynchronous.

Comment: By root level instructions I meant ```console.log('async func called');
  anotherAsync();
  console.log('async func finished');``` these 3 instructions

Comment: Seems like I did misunderstood some of the stuffs of event loop then. From event loop I thought, promises goes to microtask queue and timeouts/intervals goes to regular task queue i, e macrotask queue. Event loop waits until the callstack is empty and picks up one of the task from the queues (microtask queue has higher priority) and puts it in the callstack for execution

Comment: so I was assuming `run` would go to the queue and then immediately picked up. Then it execute `console.log` and then call `await func()`. Now the console.log of `func` would be executed, followed by `anotherAsync` call which would go to the queue. Then second console.log would be printed. Then `func` execution would end and it would be popped from the stack. Then the second console.log would be printed from `run`. Now the execution of `run` is finished and the queue would end up being empty. Lastly, eventloop would pick up `anotherAsync` from queue

Comment: But yeah got the issue here. The promise executor function does not use any existing APIs like setTimeout or setInterval. Which is why it is executed synchronously and never goes to the microtask queue